# how to get sheets name from excel 2007 (*.xlsx) using vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel-2007

I try to get sheets name from file excel using vb.net and show them into textbox. I was try with this code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Private Sub GetSheetsName
Dim efa As New Excel.Application
Dim ewb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ews As Excel.Worksheet
Dim fileName as string
fileName="D:\test.xls"
ewb = efa.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
For Each ews In ewb.Worksheets
   ExcelSheetName += ews.Name & vbNewLine
Next ews
TextBox1.text=ExcelSheetName
end sub
```

That code was work for file excel *.xls, in textbox show Sheets Name from file test.xls

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
```

But when I try with excel 2007 (*.xlsx), then show an error message like this.
[image: error message]

What should I do? Can you help me please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub GetExcelSheetNames(ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim strconn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & 
          fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(strconn)

    conn.Open()

    Dim dtSheets As DataTable = 
              conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    Dim listSheet As New List(Of String)
    Dim drSheet As DataRow

    For Each drSheet In dtSheets.Rows
        listSheet.Add(drSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString())
    Next

    //show sheetname in textbox where multiline is true
    For Each sheet As String In listSheet
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & sheet & vbNewLine
    Next

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works. But still takes time if the excel file has large number of rows >60000. Is there any way to get sheet names quickly

Answer (score 0):

An excellent library to handle xlsx files is EPPlus.

here is a sample code:

```
var existingFile = new FileInfo(path);
var sheets = new List<string>();
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    sheets.AddRange(from worksheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets where worksheet.Dimension != null select worksheet.Name);
}
```

you can find it here: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

try  using

```
For Each ews In ewb.Sheets
   ExcelSheetName += ews.Name & vbNewLine
Next ews
```